# Do we need to be enrolled in Apple Developer Program in order to install iOS app for testing in Appium on real device?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, provisioning-profile, appium-ios

Error - No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.security.application-groups, keychain-access-groups.

Comment: You do not need a paid Apple Developer Account to test apps on an iDevice from Xcode 7 onwards. If you want to put your app on the App Store and sell it then you need a paid Apple Developer Account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must have one Apple Developer Program Account if you want run any app on real devices.

If you already have one, than following the step:

1,Enter you ADP member center(developer.apple.com/account), and go into Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles;

2,Create a development certificate in Certificates;

3,Create an App IDs in Identifiers with a app bundle ID(like com.mycompny.myproject);

4,Add some new devices(which will run you app) in Devices;

5,Create an new provisioning profile using you certificate, App ID and device you just create before;

6,Then open you XCode, go into preferences, in Accounts tab, login your ADP account, select the correct team and click View Details button, download your certificate and profile;

7,At last, Open your project, change the bundle id(Project->Target->General) to the App ID you just registered.

Answer (score 1):

With XCode 8 you don't.
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

> Developing and running your app on your Apple device is as easy as entering your Apple ID into Xcode preferences. Apple Developer Program membership is not required.

Comment: Ya but I believe with Xcode 7 it only worked if you didn't have a developer account tied to your apple id previously.